# Typo in First Posts queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, spelling

If you go to the First Posts review queue, and if there's an answer in the queue and if you hover with your mouse over "No Action Needed", then you get a tooltip "this answers seems to be valid":
[image: Typo]
But it should be "this *answer* seems to be valid".

Comment: That's a ringing endorsement isn't it? Maybe change it to *"This answer **is** valid"* at least then you have _something_ to point to.

Comment: You're not supposed to hover, you're supposed to blast away on that mouse button without hesitation or thought!

Comment: Sounds like a pluralization bug. You don't want to upset Atwood.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Oh, the Horror

Comment: Noticed this too. Also, it could be a capitalization error. `this` should be `This`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing this came up again, fixing for good.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.4.4.1525, meta rev 2014.4.4.2132).